# How can you use multiple outlets in react-router 6?

Tags: react-router-dom

For example, say I have a `Header` and `Content` sub components that I would like to render on 1 page (single route path).

```
const App = () => {
  <div>
    <header><Outlet /></header>
    <content><Outlet /><content>
  </div>
}

const RouteConfig = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="/app" element={<Header />} />
        <Route path="/app" element={<Content /> />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

The above outputs the header contents for both Outlets, instead of the header *and* the contents.  Is there a way to have multipe outlets?

Comment: No, you shouldn't render more than one `Outlet` per route/path. What is the use case you are trying to solve for here?

Comment: something like this? https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#multiple-sets-of-routes

Comment: or using outlet context https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext

Comment: but generally you'd invert the relationship and just render the app multiple times

        <Route path="/app" element={<App><Header /><Content/></App>} />